# Нет доступа к записи информации в файл java

Tags: java, файлы, filewriter

При разработке программы возникла проблема, пытаюсь записать любую информацию в файл, файл создается но информация в него не записывается, файл остается пустым 
пробовал так

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2.txt"));
writer.write("henlo");
```

Результат не удовлетворяет ожидания. Создается пустой файл и все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо вызвать

```
 writer.flush();
```

или

```
 writer.close();
```

тогда все запишется...

```html
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class writer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file2.txt"));
        writer.write("he111nlo");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```